# cannot remove index.php in CodeIgniter application

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I'm deploying the web application that we made in our live server but then im having troubles in figuring out how to remove index.php.
i have read several blogs regarding how to remove index.php in codeigniter application.

i have tried this settings on my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and on my config.php

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

but i still can't figure out how to remove it. Do i need to edit something in the apache httpd.conf?

thanks!

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite enabled on your apache server?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the ? that is present after index.php in your .htaccess:

Change:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

To:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: i have changed the .htaccess into this settings

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
**RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]**
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
**RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]**
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
**RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]**  and still nothing happens

Comment: The following settings are mentioned on [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) website:

`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

This is the one I use.  Tried 3 different ones before I found one that worked

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon \.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```